# The Webhook receives a bad request from Azure Logic App even though the logic app has not returned any response

Tags: webhooks, azure-logic-apps, terminate

I have configured an Azure Logic App with an HTTP trigger and added a few actions with respect to my requirements. In the If condition false block, I used the terminate action to stop the current run for a workflow instance.

I configured the above Azure Logic App endpoint as a webhook. But sometimes the webhook receives a bad request from Azure Logic App. But in the Azure Logic App I didn’t return any response.

Can anyone suggest me Is the  issue with 'Terminate' Action or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggest me Is the issue with 'Terminate' Action or not?

No, it is not with the `Terminate` action rather it is with the HTTP Connector that you are using.
After reproducing from my end, I have observed that the below bad request is due to
502 status code which in general is caused when the server did not receive a response.

[image]

Since you are using a `HTTP Webhook` connector, the flow just loops every time the condition is true, and it never ends unless the logic app receives a response in that flow. One way to resolve this is to use a `HTTP` connector instead of `HTTP Webhook` since it doesn't require a response to complete the flow rather it just calls the URL.

[image]